# ServerSocket do not accept on Android

Tags: android, serversocket

I am looking to see if anyone else out there has had the same problem or maybe a possible solution to my problem.

It turns out my stock Evo cannot have any form of ServerSocket on the device to accept connections.  Lately I have a ServerSocket setup and I try to access it via the phone using local hosts with no success.  I have tried this once before for my application.  I have tried using 3G and WiFi.  I mainly communicate between my computer and my phone but this instance was just having my phone communicate with itself.  In my previous attempts my phone can contact my computer just fine but it doesn't work the other way around.  I've tried DatagramSocket, ServerSocket, MulticastSocket all on my phone and it can never receive any data whether coming from the computer or itself.  I have the Internet permission and I even have all the multi cast permissions.  Is there something I am missing here?  Is is possible that maybe the stock Evo is prevented completely from ever receiving a connection no matter what?

Comment: Do you have a stack trace perhaps?

Comment: very interesting problem. as this was dated way back 10 months ago, have you found anything regarding this?

Comment: I know this is ages later, but I completely forgot I had a stack overflow account for a while.  Providing some context on the old issue: There was no error traces it did nothing, After hours of research it appears some providers just blocked those type of connections to the device for no apparently reason. I ended up having to have the device do all the searching and zero receiving.